# Send field data to Integromat webhook (wp)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to send the value of a field to Integromat through a webhook. is it possible to do with document.getelementbyid ?

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jiNC.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.